# Why are Coulomb interactions modeled with just r, not r squared?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, forcefields

As far as I understand (as a complete beginner to molecular simulation and modelling), Coulomb's law for two atoms i and j is:

$$F=k\frac{q_iq_j}{(r_{ij})^2}$$

(the force is proportional to the product of the two charges and the **inverse square** of the distance)

I am trying to understand molecular simulation and force fields and many use this formula but without squaring the distance, is there a reason behind this? My best thought is simply to improve computational time complexity as this is often the most computationally expensive step and quadratic terms scale worse than linear ones.

Comment: The force field does not use the force equations. It uses the Coulomb electrostatic potential instead, that's why.

Answer (score 10):

The force $F$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{r^2}$ but the potential $V$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{r}$.

This is because $F$ is proportional to $\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$, the derivative of $V$ with respect to $r$ (this is by definition).

Using $r$ instead of $r^2$ is not to save computational time (it is incorrect to think that calculating $r*r$ is more computationally expensive than calculating $q_1*q_2$). It is simply the correct Coulomb potential corresponding to the Coulomb force that you correctly wrote.

Comment: Just to double check, you're saying that because force on an atom can be written as the negative derivative of the potential energy ($-\nabla{V}({r})$) then the (negative) derivative of 1/r is 1/r^2 and this is used because the force field is a summation of potential energy terms (not forces)? Thanks so much for your help with this

Comment: The derivative of 1/r^2 is not 1/r. However, you have the right idea: when you see 1/r in the context of Coulomb interactions, it's the potential, not the force. A "force field" is technically a field of forces (not potentials), but we tend to use "potential energy fields" in MD software, even if people don't tend to use that term. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_field_(chemistry)) you can see that a "force field" is indeed defined as a field of forces in the first sentence, but then for the majority of the article, energies are discussed instead.

Comment: sorry I think I meant the other way around that the derivative of 1/r is (negative) 1/r^2 - though does that not matter? I'm still slightly confused how to get to 1/r for the potential. Other than that, yeah it can be a little confusing reading the literature with no prior background, I appreciate your explainer!

Comment: If you want to get to 1/r for the potential, starting with 1/r^2 for the force, then you can do [the integral of 1/r^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+1%2Fr%5E2) and add the negative sign.

Comment: ah, yes - that makes complete sense, thank you!! Help and patience so very much appreciated